# Percentages of web using mapping softwares

Tags: mapping, online

How accurate are the online mapping assessments on trends.builtwith.com?
http://trends.builtwith.com/mapping
[image: online mapping pie chart]

Can ArcGIS really be only .33% ?
If so, what does this say about ArcGIS.

Also why aren't QGIS Server, GeoServer, or MapServer listed ?

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding what is being measured!

This graph seems to look at what web mapping javascript APIs are used on web pages,  and it makes sense that things like QGIS or Mapserver are not counted,  because they are not javascript mapping libraries!